# QSerialPort reading and writing not working

Tags: qt, arduino

When I run the Qt code below to connect to ESP32 with Arduino code I don't get the expected result which is QDebug() printing the QByteArray com -----> \xFF \xFC \xFE \xFC.

Instead I get the last or the first value in the com byte array (\xFC or \xFF).

I'm also getting a warning when I call the connect() function "QIODevice::readyRead is not a signal".

What am I doing wrong?

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    :QDialog(parent),
      ui(new Ui::Dialog),
      esp(new QSerialPort(this))

{

ui->setupUi(this);
esp_available = false;

void Dialog::on_connect_clicked()
{
    if(esp_available){
        esp->setPortName(espPortName);
        esp->open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);
        esp->setBaudRate(500000);
        esp->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        esp->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        esp->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        esp->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

        connect(esp, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &Dialog::onDataReady);
        // line above gives warning: QIODevice::readyRead is not a signal

}

void Dialog::on_startStream_clicked()
{
    QByteArray com = QByteArray::fromHex({"ff fc fe fc"});
    if(esp->isOpen()){
        esp->write(com);
    }
}

void Dialog::onDataReady()
{
    QByteArray ba;
    do{
        ba += esp->readAll();
        int i = ba.indexOf('\r');
        if(i != -1){
            QByteArray ba1 = ba.mid(0, i);
            qDebug() << ba1;
            ba.remove(0, i);
        }
    } while(esp->bytesAvailable());
}
```

Arduino code running on ESP32:

```
bool packet_recevived = false;
const int max_packet_size = 10;
char incoming_packet[max_packet_size];  // the incoming packet size mat vary.
void parse_packet();

void setup() { Serial.begin(500000); }

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0 && packet_recevived == false) {
        parse_packet();
    } else if (packet_recevived == true) {
        packet_recevived = false;
    }
}

void parse_packet() {
    int in_size = Serial.available();
    for (int i = 0; i <= in_size; i++) {
        incoming_packet[i] = Serial.read();
    }
    Serial.println(incoming_packet);
    packet_recevived = true;
}
```

AMENDMENT:

I modified the onDatReady() slot as follows:

```
void Dialog::onDataReady()
{
    QByteArray ba;

    if(esp->canReadLine()){
        ba = esp->readLine();
        qDebug() << ba;

    }
}
```

As suggested by @eyllanesc in the comments I tried decreasing the baud rate and tried different ones. 9600 and 19200 seem to work fine. Does Qt not support a custom baud rate of 500K? Perhaps the connect() function or readyRead() signal is not fast enough? Any suggestions?

Comment: move `esp->open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite);` after `connect(esp, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &Dialog::onDataReady);`. In any communication protocol, the rules are first established and then the communication begins. Instead you are opening the port and then you tell it how you are going to "speak".

Comment: done but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Why do you use 500000 as baudrate? For example the typical is to use 115200. Change `esp->setBaudRate(500000);` to `esp->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);`, and `Serial.begin(500000);` to `Serial.begin(115200);` .

Comment: I'm getting a lot of data from a sensor a 24bit ADC at 250 samples per second x 24 channels.

Comment: @eyllanesc please my amended post. Seems like decreasing the baud rate worked. Does Qt not support a custom baud of 500K? could it be the connect() or readyRead() signal is not fast enough? any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my Arduino code which I fixed.

```
char incoming_buffer[11];
void process();
void execute(uint8_t com[], int size);
bool received = false;
String command;
bool executed = false;
uint8_t start_stream[] = "\x02\x00\x01\xFE\x01\x00\x01";

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(500000);
    Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0 && received == false) {
        process();
    } else if (executed == true) {
        executed = false;
        received = false;
    }
}
void process() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', incoming_buffer, 11);
    }
    command = String(incoming_buffer);
    if (command == "start") {
        execute(start_stream, sizeof(start_stream));
        received = true;
    } else {
        Serial.println("no command");
        received = false;
    }
    memset(incoming_buffer, 0, sizeof(incoming_buffer));  // reset the buffer
}

void execute(uint8_t com[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        Serial.print(com[i]);
        Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println();
    executed = true;
}
```